# is it possible to use cron too much?

Tags: mysql, cron

I run a game statistics site. Its MySQL database is small potatoes compared to most of the things people work on around here, but shared hosting does necessitate an eye on query optimization, particularly when performing lots of joins and sub-queries.

Earlier this week I moved a rather slow (~0.5s) query that grouped, counted, averaged, and sorted the ratings of members to a nightly cron job. Results are stored in a table.

Because we average about one new rating per day, the change does not cause any perceptible data inaccuracy to my users, AND the new query which just grabs rows from the table runs in the ~0.000X range, so all pages pulling that data are noticeably faster.

Clearly this is a good thing!

And as I sat there basking in the glow of my cron job, my mind started running through other aspects of the site and mentally tagging those that could be cron'd... (many)

Which leads me to wonder - **is it possible to use cron too much?**

Because my site's database changes about once a day, I could conceivably run ALL complex queries (there are *many*) through nightly cron jobs and store the results in tables.

Is there ever a downside? (apart from data occasionally not being up-to-the-second accurate?)

Comment: _"rather slow (~0.5s) query"_ heh... thanks for a good laugh `*snif*`

Comment: @Matt Ball - hey, if you've got 30 on a page and they're all 0.5s, you've lost your visitor! :-) *(like I said, small potatoes!)*

Comment: Only if they run serially ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron is great; it's usually a good thing to refrain from reinventing wheels. Some applications have more precise needs than cron can accommodate, so that's one reason not to use it. Also, distributing and managing cronjobs that are to form an integral part of your app can be difficult and error-prone, especially absent a competent package manager from the OS. Troubleshooting can be a little bit of a pain, particularly when there's one server missing one of its 100 cronjobs or something, but that can be managed with an OS package manager or with something like puppet.

But my opinion is to use cron whenever you can and makes sense, rather than rolling your own.

Answer (score 1):

You're not beginning to approach the limits of what amount of jobs can (or should) be scheduled with `cron`. You'll be just fine. :)

You might want to consider a worker-message queue like [gearman](http://gearman.org/#introduction) to trigger jobs that should be run 'after the fact', but not necessarily on a fixed schedule.

Answer (score 0):

how about one cron job that runs all your procedures?

I once worked on a unix system that failed pretty miserably after the cron job queue exceeded 20 entries.  The queue did not execute on any predictable cycle - i.e. FILO, FIFO LIFO etc. it simply was randomized

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using triggers to keep your summary statistics up to date.  There's also an event scheduler in MySQL 5.1+ if you like running queries periodically.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html